# How to write credential back to vault with jenkins vault plugin

Tags: jenkins, hashicorp-vault

I know how to retrieve credential from vault in jenkinsfile.
Now I have a task, need to generate a new credential and then set back to vault.
Can I do that with jenkins vault plugin?

Can anyone provide a easy and secured way to store credentials into vault?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using the Jenkins Vault plugin, but you can easily write a secret in Vault using Jenkins, the Vault API, and a Vault token got with the plugin.

You just need to execute something like this:

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: VAULT-TOKEN" --data @- --request POST https://VAULT-SERVER/v1/kv/data/SECRET-PATH <<EOF
{
    "data":
    {
        "KEY1" : "VALUE1",
        "KEY2" : "VALUE2"
    }
}
EOF
```